# Error } in resizebox (missing $)

Tags: tables, math-mode

The text is divided into two columns, the table does not fit in the column, so we decided to use resizebox, but the compiler produces an error on the bracket } (`missing $ inserted resizebox`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10.9pt,two column]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\graphicspath{{pictures/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy} %колонтитул
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{132} 
\fancyhead[R]{К.Д. Демаков, В.А. Старостин, С.Г. Шемардов}
\fancyfoot[R]{Журнал технической физики,2002, том 72, вып.10} 

\begin{document}
\parindent=0cm
ника не дает решения с максимумом, расположенным дальше пробега ионов источника от границы.Важным моментом модели является ее неравновесность~-— диффузия просиходит на фоне интенсивного рождения и аннигиляции дефектов. Эти процессы описываются следующей системой связанных уравнений:

$${\partial n_{a}}\!/{\partial t} =D_{a} {\partial^2 n_{a}}\!/{\partial x^{2}} - n_{a} n_{v} k_{cap} + n_{c} n_{d} k_{act}$$
\begin{equation}
+j_{0exp}(-{R_{p}-x+x_{0}}^{2}/2\Delta{{R_{p}}^{2}})/\sqrt{2}\pi \Delta {R_{p}},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
{\partial n_{c}}\!/{\partial t}= n_{a} n_{v} k_{cap} - n_c n_{d} k_{act} , 
\end{equation}

$$ {\partial n_{d}}\!/{\partial t}=D_{dV} {\partial^{2} n_{d}\!/{\partial x^{2}}-n_{c} n_{d} - k_{act}} $$

\begin{equation}
-n_{V} n_{d} k_{ann} + j_{0} N \sigma_{d} \Theta(R_{p}-x+ x_{0}),
\end{equation}

$${\partial n_{V}}\!/{\partial t}= D_{dV} {\partial^{2} n_{d}}\!/{\partial x^{2}}- n_{a} n_{V} - k_{cap} $$

$$
- n_{V} n_{d} k_{ann} + j_{0} N \sigma_{d}\Theta(R_{p} -x+ x_{0}),$$

\qquad
$x_{0}$=-$v_{b}$t,\quad $N=5.04*10^{22} cm^{-3}$ ,

\begin{equation}
\sigma_d=3.52*10^{-16} cm^{2}
\end{equation}

где $\Theta(x)$ ~-— единичная ступенька; $N$ ~---плотность ядер кремния;$\sigma_{d}$ ~---ориентировачное сечение образования дефекта;$R_p$ и $\Delta{R}_{p}$ - пробег иона и его разброс; $D_{a}$,$D_{dV}$, $k_{cap}$, $k_{act}$,$k_{ann}$ -свободные параметры модели с очевидным физическим смыслом коэффициентов диффузии примеси и пар дефект ~— вакансий и скоростей квазихимических реакций захвата примеси вакансиями, активации примеси междоузлиями и взаимной аннигиляции вакансий и междоузолий соответственно.

\parindent=0.4cm
Условие на границе для примеси выбиралось нулевым исходя из эксперимента, что можно интерпретировать

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{arara.JPG}
\caption{Зависимость энтальпии миграции дефектов в кремнии от температурыпо данным табл. 2 и 4.}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\setcounter{table}{1}
\caption{Рассчитанные диффузионные коэффициенты и энтальпии} 
\resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}
{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
№ & $D_{a}$,$\frac{cm^2}{s}*10^{-11}$ & $0D_{dV}$,$\frac{cm^{2}}{s}*10^{-11}$ & $H_{dV}$, $cal/mol &T_{eff}, °K$ \\ \hline
$1$ & $0.169$ & $0.204$ & $64610$ & $1326$ \\
$2$ & $0.540$& \hspace{5pt}$0.0633$ & $68151$ & $1335$ \\
$3$ & $0.007$ & \hspace{5pt}$0.0463$ & $47157$ & $4913$ \\
$4 & $0.499$ & \hspace{5pt}$0.0127$ & $31937$ & $589$ \\

\end{tabular} 
} 
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\setcounter{table}{2}
\caption{Рассчитанные скорости квазиохимических реакций} 

\resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}
{
\begin{tabular}{c|с|с|c}
\hline
№ & $K_{cap}$,$\frac{cm^{3}}{s}*10^{-23}$ & $K_{act}$,$\frac{cm^{3}}{s}*10^{-23}$ & $K_{ann}$,$\frac{cm^{3}}{s}*10^{-23}$ \\ \hline
$1$ & $2.355$ & $7.421$ & $2.609$ \\ 
$2$ & $0.889$ & $8.321$ & $5.795$ \\
$3$ & $0.943$ & $15.60$ & $5.763$ \\
$4$ & $0.929$ & $8.260$ & $5.855$ \\

\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\setcounter{table}{3}
\caption{Рассчитанные энтальпии для других экспериментов}

\resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}
{
\begin{tabular}{с|с|с|с|с|с|с}
\hline
$Ion$ & $T,°C$ & $j_{0}, \frac{\mu A}{cm^{2]}$ & $E, keV$ & $T_{eff}, K$ & $H_{dV},cal/mol$ & $Reference$\\ \hline
$Yb$ &
$20$ & $10$ & $70$ & $488$ & $27811^*$ & $[5,6]$ \\
& & & & & $26877$ & \\
& & & & & $24697$ & \\
$Na$ & $365$ & $0.3$ & $7$ & $638$ & $35845$ & $[7]$ \\
$As$ & $20$ & $150$ & $25$ & $722$ & $38703$ & $[8]$ \\
$Tm$ & $500$ & $30$ & $150$ & $906$ & $50900$ & $[9]$ \\
$C$ & $20$ & $300$ & $40$ & $961$ & $46377^*$ & $[2,10]$ \\
& & & & & $46931$ & \\ 
& & & & & $47058&$ & \\
$As$ & $850$ & $40$ & $40$ & $1143$ & $57164$ & $[12]$ \\
$Tl$ & $1200$ & $40$ & $20$ & $1478$ & $70591$ & $[3]$ \\
$As$ & $1200$ & $40$& $40$ & $1482$ & $74154$ & $[11]$ \\
$Tl$ & $1200$ & $100$ & $20$ & $1484$ & $700644$ & $[4]$ \\

\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}

как ее испарение с поверхности образца. Для междоузлий и вакансий использовалось такое условие, чтобы поток поток междоузлий вызывал смещение границы вещества со скоростью $V_b$ (задача типа Стефана). Начальные условия и условия на противоположной границе брались нулевые. Система уравнений (1)~-(4) при вышеописанных начальных и граничных условиях решалась численно на ЭВМ методом конечных разностей. Значения свободных параметров модели подбирались методом наименьших квадратов так, чтобы наилучшим образом соответствовать экспериментальным профилям.
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

errors in tables:
1)

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\setcounter{table}{1}
\caption{Рассчитанные диффузионные коэффициенты и энтальпии} 
\resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}
{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
№ & $D_{a}$,$\frac{cm^2}{s}*10^{-11}$ & $0D_{dV}$,$\frac{cm^{2}}{s}*10^{-11}$ & $H_{dV}$, $cal/mol &T_{eff}, °K$ \\ \hline
$1$ & $0.169$ & $0.204$ & $64610$ & $1326$ \\
$2$ & $0.540$& \hspace{5pt}$0.0633$ & $68151$ & $1335$ \\
$3$ & $0.007$ & \hspace{5pt}$0.0463$ & $47157$ & $4913$ \\
$4 & $0.499$ & \hspace{5pt}$0.0127$ & $31937$ & $589$ \\

\end{tabular} 
} 
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

2)

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\setcounter{table}{2}
\caption{Рассчитанные скорости квазихимических реакций} 

\resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}
{
\begin{tabular}{c|с|с|c}
\hline
№ & $K_{cap}$,$\frac{cm^{3}}{s}*10^{-23}$ & $K_{act}$,$\frac{cm^{3}}{s}*10^{-23}$ & $K_{ann}$,$\frac{cm^{3}}{s}*10^{-23}$ \\ \hline
$1$ & $2.355$ & $7.421$ & $2.609$ \\ 
$2$ & $0.889$ & $8.321$ & $5.795$ \\
$3$ & $0.943$ & $15.60$ & $5.763$ \\
$4$ & $0.929$ & $8.260$ & $5.855$ \\

\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

3)

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\setcounter{table}{3}
\caption{Рассчитанные энтальпии для других экспериментов}

\resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}
{
\begin{tabular}{с|с|с|с|с|с|с}
\hline
$Ion$ & $T,°C$ & $j_{0}, \frac{\mu A}{cm^{2]}$ & $E, keV$ & $T_{eff}, K$ & $H_{dV},cal/mol$ & $Reference$\\ \hline
$Yb$ &
$20$ & $10$ & $70$ & $488$ & $27811^*$ & $[5,6]$ \\
& & & & & $26877$ & \\
& & & & & $24697$ & \\
$Na$ & $365$ & $0.3$ & $7$ & $638$ & $35845$ & $[7]$ \\
$As$ & $20$ & $150$ & $25$ & $722$ & $38703$ & $[8]$ \\
$Tm$ & $500$ & $30$ & $150$ & $906$ & $50900$ & $[9]$ \\
$C$ & $20$ & $300$ & $40$ & $961$ & $46377^*$ & $[2,10]$ \\
& & & & & $46931$ & \\ 
& & & & & $47058&$ & \\
$As$ & $850$ & $40$ & $40$ & $1143$ & $57164$ & $[12]$ \\
$Tl$ & $1200$ & $40$ & $20$ & $1478$ & $70591$ & $[3]$ \\
$As$ & $1200$ & $40$& $40$ & $1482$ & $74154$ & $[11]$ \\
$Tl$ & $1200$ & $100$ & $20$ & $1484$ & $700644$ & $[4]$ \\

\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: I shared the code in parts. Thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 5):

This is more of an extended comment than a real answer ... anyway:

- please in future provide complete small document starting with `\documentclas{...}` followed only by the necessary packages, `\begin{document}` and your LaTeX code, then ending with `\end{document}`. Without it we can only guess about your problem
- if it is possible, don't use `resizebox`
- the look of tables can be significantly improved (of course according to one's taste) with the usage of rules from the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline` and the omission of vertical lines. Employ the `S` column type from the package `siunitx`, which provides correct typesetting of SI units
- a short review of your code shows that you need a proofreader and not (only)  LaTeX help (in some rows the number of ampersand is larger than declared, etc, also other typing errors are present)
- it is good habit that to mimic table columns also in the typescript. In this way you will have better control over the number of columns, necessary `&` and `$` and so on.

I'll only fix your first table (if you like the suggested solution, you can redesign the other tables in a similar way). I omit the use of `\resizebox` since it is not clear if you realy need it. A better approach is using smaller font size (for example `small` or reduce `\tabcolsep` for example to half of its default value with `\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}` before the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
%   \begin{table}[htb]
%   caption
%\resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}
%{
%\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{l   S[table-format=4.0]
                    S[table-format=3.1]
                    S[table-format=3.0]
                    S[table-format=3.0]
                    S[table-format=6.0,
                      table-space-text-post={*}]
                l}
    \toprule
\thead[t]{Ion}
    & {\thead[t]{$T$\\ \si{\degreeCelsius}} }  
            & {\thead[t]{$j_{0}$\\ \si{\micro\ampere/cm^2}}}
                    & {\thead[t]{$E$\\ \si{keV}}}
                            & {\thead[t]{$T_{\textit{eff}}$\\ \si{\kelvin}}}
                                    & {\thead[t]{$H_{dV}$\\ \si{cal/mol}}}
                                                & {\thead[t]{Ref.}} \\
    \midrule
Yb  & 20    & 10    & 70    & 488   & 27811*    & [5,6]     \\
    &       &       &       &       & 26877     &           \\
    &       &       &       &       & 24697     &           \\
Na  & 365   & 0.3   & 7     & 638   & 35845     & [7]       \\
As  & 20    & 150   & 25    & 722   & 38703     & [8]       \\
Tm  & 500   & 30    & 150   & 906   & 50900     & [9]       \\
C   & 20    & 300   & 40    & 961   & 46377*    & [2,10]    \\
    &       &       &       &       & 46931     &           \\
    &       &       &       &       & 47058     &           \\
As  & 850   & 40    & 40    & 1143  & 57164     & [12]      \\
Tl  & 1200  & 40    & 20    & 1478  & 70591     & [3]       \\
As  & 1200  & 40    & 40    & 1482  & 74154     & [11]      \\
Tl  & 1200  & 100   & 20    & 1484  & 700644    & [4]       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%}
%    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Chemical elements are normally typeset with upright type, not as math variables. I fixed this too.